# How to get an object of a subclass of an immutable library (best practice)?

Tags: scala, immutability

Let's assume, we have an immutable library with a class `ImmutableFoo`:

```
scala> class ImmutableFoo(x: Int) {
         def add(y: Int): ImmutableFoo = new ImmutableFoo(x + y)
       }
defined class ImmutableFoo
```

An object of this class, of course, does not change its state by adding `y` to `x`, but creates a new object of the class. So far so good.

Now we want to create a immutable subclass. First try:

```
scala> class subImmutableFoo(x: Int) extends ImmutableFoo(x)
defined class subImmutableFoo
```

But when we add a number, we don't get an object of the subclass:

```
scala> (new subImmutableFoo(5)).add(6)
res0: ImmutableFoo = ImmutableFoo@1ee69d3
```

What is a best practice way to solve this issue ?

One solution could be to override the method in the subclass and create an object of the subclass. This solution is simple in this case, but can lead to have a lot of double code (base class + subclass) when methods are bigger. Or even much more double code when we create mutliple subclasses and override the method.

Answer (score 1):

Take it as a `MyType` problem, you can do this:

```
class ImmutableFoo[T <: ImmutableFoo[T] : Manifest](x: Int) {
  def add(y: Int): T = implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[Int]).newInstance((x+y).asInstanceOf[Object]).asInstanceOf[T]
}

class SubImmutableFoo(x: Int) extends ImmutableFoo[SubImmutableFoo](x) 

new SubImmutableFoo(2).add(4)
```

And you can define an `Addable` type class for the `add` operation. It is too much code for this case but this pattern is more generic.

```
trait Addable[T] { 
  def plus(a:T, i:Int):T

  class Infix(x:T) {
    def add(i:Int):T = plus(x, i)
  }
}

class ImmutableFoo(val x:Int)  
class SubImmutableFoo(override val x:Int) extends ImmutableFoo(x)

implicit object AddableFoo extends Addable[ImmutableFoo]{
  override def plus(a:ImmutableFoo, i:Int) = new ImmutableFoo(a.x+i)
}

implicit object AddableSub extends Addable[SubImmutableFoo]{
  override def plus(a:SubImmutableFoo, i:Int) = new SubImmutableFoo(a.x+i)
}

implicit def infix[T: Addable](x:T) = {
  val addable = implicitly[Addable[T]]
  new addable.Infix(x) 
}

new ImmutableFoo(3) add 4  // ImmutableFoo
new SubImmutableFoo(2) add 1 // SubImmutableFoo
```

Answer (score 1):

On a variation of the 'MyType' pattern, you could do the following which does not use manifests or reflection:

```
trait Immu[+Repr <: Immu[Repr]] {
   def x: Int
   def add(y: Int): Repr = newInstance(x + y)
   protected def newInstance(x: Int): Repr
}

class Foo(val x: Int) extends Immu[Foo] {
   def show: String = "Immu(" + x + ")"
   protected def newInstance(x: Int) = new Foo(x)
}

class Bar(x0: Int) extends Foo(x0) with Immu[Bar] {
   def mul(y: Int): Bar = newInstance(x * y)
   override protected def newInstance(x: Int) = new Bar(x)
}

new Foo(3).add(4).show
new Bar(3).add(4).mul(2).show
```

Of course, in turn it assumes that you do not vary the number of constructor arguments needed.